# Firefox pocket button - "Already added" status

Tags: ubuntu, firefox

I'm using Mozilla Firefox 48.0 with pocket integration and I think this service can be useful for quickly gathering pages into temporary reading lists.

But I've an issue with the pocket button in Firefox toolbar. The button doesn't display the "already added" status of current page. If I'm visiting a page, I cannot tell if it is already present in my pocket list or not. The pocket toolbar icon stays same regardless of said status of the page. I cannot even find out the status by clicking the icon since clicking the icon simply saves current page into my pocket list.

So, how to find out if current page is in my pocket list? I expect the button to change color or have some clear visual indication if I've already saved current page in my list. Also I should be able to find out what tags I saved current page under from within Firefox (and without digging deep into menus).

Is there a way that I can configure the pocket feature in Firefox?

Thanks.

**Edit**

I just checked pocket extension in chromium. It appears to be working as expected.

[image]

I displays a red icon for saved pages. Even though it doesn't show the tags the page was saved with, it is still good enough.

Comment: Come on guys...

Comment: Same issue here! I am using FF 45.4.0 ESR version. Did you find any solution?

Comment: I've this issue with chrome addon (Brave). Until now, i've only used in Android without issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly, this feature is actually not supported by Pocket (at least now) - which is really inconvenient.

Check the following bug report https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1173827 - if you register to Bugzilla you will be able to vote for the issue, so hopefully gets fixed at some point.

It is very inconvenient to land to a page and not knowing it it is already pocketed, which can end up in you adding it again and having duplicated pages.